# Load balance execution of UI tests (Selenium) on multiple identical app instances (URLs)

Tags: ant, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, junit4, parallel-testing

I am trying to run UI tests on multiple identical instances of the web application. For example, let's say the identical version of the application is available at 3 places:

- https://some1.app.com
- https://some2.app.com
- https://some3.app.com

The intended system should check which instance is available and run a test (that is not already run) on it. It should be able to run 3 tests on the 3 instances simultaneously in the Jenkins environment.

I have explored the Jenkins Matrix Configuration, but that appears to run all tests on all possible combinations in the matrix. My intention is to divide and load balance the tests, not run on all combinations. Any ideas on how this can be done?

I am using JUnit4 with Ant for running the tests on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be a [Matrix Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin). You could configure your url as parameter a bit like in here: [Building a matrix project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)

Comment: Thanks Pekka. I will try using this one. Could you please tell if this plugin is known to be capable to do what I am looking for?

Comment: I think it is very close. You need to set your app address as user defined axis and configure your selenium to use this variable. Then Jenkins will run all three jobs simultaneously in different executors.

Comment: I tried using it. It appears that Jenkins runs all the configuration of the matrix (really a cross-product). My intention is to load balance and divide the tests on the matrix, not run all the tests on all configs. Any idea how that might be done?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood your situation. Is this what you meant: if only some1 is up, you want to run all tests against that. If some1 and some2 are up, you want to split tests 50-50 between them. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, for simplicity sake you can assume that some1 and some2 will always be up. I am trying to solve the problem with fixed number of URLs and then scale it to more URLs.